# Parse installation returning false

Tags: php, android, parse-platform

I am creating an app using phonegap. I want to use parse push notification. I am trying to install my app on parse using PHP. I have seen installation process on [this tutorial](https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-uploading).
After that i have tried following:-

```
    $APPLICATION_ID = "8duVhrDRACPwXr8lY0dfsdsdfsdvUH";
$REST_API_KEY = "oIMqyqweSELdgiosdfsdwerWq8IxJ7Kv";

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/installations';

$data = array(
   'deviceType' => 'android',
    'deviceToken' => 'APA91bEnL9hUgExuwrmFchzfpmHG79zfmdIDLP5nZfsdfstdimbGQFMlIOR2PyGcXdFAaM3S6U2rzMEt8Hl3UdiagonwMCMQ209_rrDqVp91jVtLFtfcrBLQNCM4HloMrzlkv5gGp0sLP7Ie9sdfYiaxdO3QHdp64',
    );
$_data = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),

);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $response=curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($response);
```

I am not sure why it is returning false. I have checked app id,rest api id and device token. Is There any error in my code.

Comment: Have you got any sloution ............ I need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing the **`cURL`** do like this

```
$response = curl_exec($curl); // <-- Add this before your var_dump.
var_dump($response);
```